# Accidentally used high heat on Teflon pan!

Tags: teflon

I accidentally left a Teflon pan on high heat to the point where oil was smoking a lot. Is the Teflon pan still good to use? I'm afraid I destroyed the protective coating. I visually inspected the coating and it seems to be intact and in good shape.

Comment: What does the surface of the pan look like now?  Damaged teflon won't be smooth any more

Comment: Hi, health related questions are off topic here. I had to remove that part. We can only answer the aspect of the pan being difficult to cook with or not.

Answer (score 3):

Smoking oil generally isn't hot enough to damage teflon.  Generally, Teflon [gets damaged at 260C/500F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene#Safety), which is [above the smoke point of most cooking oils](https://www.seriouseats.com/2014/05/cooking-fats-101-whats-a-smoke-point-and-why-does-it-matter.html) (though not all of them).  So as long as you didn't let it go to the point where you burned most of the oil off, it should be OK.

Comment: Hm.. thanks for the link. I was actually using avocado oil which your reference says burns at 271 °C.

Comment: Um ... no?  The linked article says that avocado oil burns at 205C.

Comment: "there are at least two cooking oils (refined safflower oil at 265 °C (509 °F) and avocado oil at 271 °C (520 °F)) that have a higher smoke point."

Comment: Ah, interesting, that's not in the chart.   So were you using refined or virgin avocado oil?  

Of course, a visual inspection of the surface is probably your best bet now.